# My function to find LCM of n numbers failing only in certain type of cases. What's wrong in my code?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning basic programming on my own a few months back. So pardon if my question seems silly.

While trying to solve one of the freecodecamp's Javascript challenges, I wrote the following code to find out the lowest common multiple (LCM) of n numbers in an array. My code is passing all the tests but the last one. The freecodecamp is not showing any error too. so I am unable to understand what's wrong in my code that's failing only the last test?

The array (arr) given as input to the function consists of 2 numbers and the problem statement asks to find the LCM of all the numbers within this range (inclusive of these 2 numbers).

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  function allNumsArr(x) {
    let y = [];
    for (let i = Math.min(...x); i <= Math.max(...x); i++) {
      y.push(i);
    }
    return y;
  };

  var allInArr = allNumsArr(arr);

  function findHCF(x,y) {
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (x === y) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return findHCF(Math.max(x,y) - Math.min(x,y), Math.min(x,y));
    }
  };
  /* The above is calculated as per the Euclid's algorithm to find the HCF/GCD */

  var hcfOfAll = allInArr.reduce((a,b) => findHCF(a,b));
  return allInArr.reduce((a,b) => ((a * b)/(findHCF(a,b))));
};
console.log(
smallestCommons([1, 5]), //should return a number.
smallestCommons([1, 5]), //should return 60.
smallestCommons([5, 1]), //should return 60.
smallestCommons([2, 10]), //should return 2520.
smallestCommons([1, 13]), //should return 360360.
smallestCommons([23, 18]), //should return 6056820.
)
```

Following are the tests provided by freecodecamp. All the test pass except the last one.